# How to retrieve leads from pipedrive, with current stage of the lead?

Tags: python, pandas, pipedrive-api

My task is to fetch leads from Pipedrive with their current stage, as well as the lead creation date and the date of the last stage update.

I have a code that retrieves all this data through the API, but for some reason, it doesn't return the stage.

How can I solve this issue?

[image]

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

# Your Pipedrive API token
API_TOKEN = "TOKEN"

# Function to fetch leads and their details
def fetch_leads():
    leads = []
    start = 1000
    limit = 500

    while True:
        url = f"https://api.pipedrive.com/v1/leads?api_token={API_TOKEN}&start={start}&limit={limit}&include_deleted=0"
        response = requests.get(url)

        if response.status_code == 200:
            data = response.json()
            leads_data = data.get("data")
            if leads_data:
                leads += leads_data

            # Check if there are more leads to fetch
            pagination = response.headers.get("Link")
            if pagination:
                next_link = get_next_link_from_pagination(pagination)
                if next_link:
                    start += limit
                    continue

        break

    return leads

# Function to fetch the current stage of a lead
def fetch_current_stage(lead_id):
    url = f"https://api.pipedrive.com/v1/leads/{lead_id}?api_token={API_TOKEN}"
    response = requests.get(url)

    if response.status_code == 200:
        data = response.json()
        stages = data.get("data").get("stages")
        if stages and len(stages) > 0:
            current_stage = stages[-1].get("stage_id").get("name")
            return current_stage

    return None

# Create an empty DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Lead ID", "Current Stage", "Creation Date", "Last Update Date"])

# Fetch leads and retrieve their details
leads = fetch_leads()

# Iterate through each lead and retrieve the desired information
for lead in leads:
    lead_id = lead.get("id")
    creation_date = lead.get("add_time")
    last_update_date = lead.get("update_time")

    # Fetch the current stage of the lead
    current_stage = fetch_current_stage(lead_id)

    # Append lead details to the DataFrame
    df = df.append({"Lead ID": lead_id, "Current Stage": current_stage, "Creation Date": creation_date, "Last Update Date": last_update_date}, ignore_index=True)

# Print the DataFrame
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Pipedrive, the Lead is not entering your pipeline (each pipeline have stages in it), and as a result, lead does not have a *stage_id* assigned to it.

You can only get stage_id of a Deal: https://developers.pipedrive.com/docs/api/v1/Deals#getDeal